# Can I check for object properties in a switch statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to process a range of possible responses from an AJAX request and want to do this in a switch statement.

`data.message` holds the information I'm interested in, however it can be returned as either a string or a JSON object

Testing for a string is simple enough, but I want to know if I can do something like this:

```
switch (data.message) {
    case 'ok':
        ...
    case 'another string':
        ...
    case (this.id == 123):
        ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can do this.

Comment: I'll be contrary. No. That's not how `switch` statements work.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Simple answer is no, it is not supported,

As a workaround you may try to use following form of switch:

```
switch (true) {
    case (data.message === 'ok'):
        ...
    case (data.message === 'another string'):
        ...
    case (data.message.id == 123):
        ...
}
```

This may look better than list of if-else statements

Comment: That's pretty horrible tho. Use an if statement. Much clearer.

Comment: @Andy It depends... Time from time it looks better than if-else list, and also easier to read, as far as I understand we are not talking about 3 if-else statements, but rather 10-20 in a row....

Comment: I was going to post this note, but I'll add it as a comment here, since it points to the reference for this particular usage.

There is an interesting (and somewhat strange-looking) use of the switch statement on the MDN documentation site:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#Rewriting_multiple_If_statements_with_Switch

Comment: If I saw that in a code review I would ask the developer to rewrite it. I just don't think it shows the _intention_ of the code particularly well. Personal opinion obvs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However I think at this point it's probably better to stick to a bunch of if/else statements

Comment: It's a good workaround, particularly if you want to use the 'default' for all the other keys, in the object, that don't fit upper, in the switch. There could be 1, 2 or a million. And if you want to account precisely for that, this is a nice approach.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by first converting the object into json (using `JSON.stringify()`) and than testing against the json representation. Just make sure that you don't include any extra spaces as this needs to be strictly the same json (best to grab the value by inspecting `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))`).

This would be something like:

```
           switch (JSON.stringify(data)) {
                case '{"message":"your message","anotherPropety":"another value"}' : {
                   // your logic             
                   break;
                }
                default: {
                    // your logic
                }
            }
```